# Reference CSS file in my includes/header.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a `header.php` file that is called in all the pages. This header file contains a menu bar. The menu bar has been modified and the new item includes opening a pop-up div on click. This div reference a few `css` and `javascript` files. How can I add these files to the header considering I cannot have a `head` tag in the `header.php` file. The solution that has failed to work is:

```
<style>
<?php include '../../css/base.css'; ?>
</style>
```

Comment: If header.php is called in all the pages, then why don't you include that css in head tag.

Comment: Or you may copy your css in header.php

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen It did not have the css in the pop-up div.

Comment: @IrfanAhmed I cannot have a head tab in my header.php because this is called in all files that already have a head tag

Answer (score 1):

Link to an external CSS and Javascript file, they don't need to be in the `<head>` section.

To add css use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your/css/file">
```

To add javascript

```
 <script src="path/to/your/js/file"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../css/base.css">
```